# GtkButton label updates

Tags: user-interface, gtk, glade, gtkbutton

I am designing a GUI using C, Glade, and Gtk.

I have some signals configured in glade to update the labels of various widgets, mainly GtkButton and GtkLabel. The overall functionality is that when a certain radio button is clicked, all button and labels change in response (language selection).

I am using the function gtk_label_set_label(...) in the widgets _draw() function and it works as expected (text changes, g_print occurs (once)).

```
gboolean on_lblMyLabel_draw(GtkLabel *label, gpointer *user_data) {
    gtk_label_set_label(label, "custom text");
    g_print("%s\n", "custom text");
    return FALSE;
}
```

However, when I attempt the same from a button,

```
gboolean on_btnMyButton_draw(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data) {
    gtk_button_set_label(button, "custom text");
    g_print("%s\n", "custom text");
    return FALSE;
}
```

The text does not update, but dissappears, and the g_print() statement prints forever (as if the draw is recursively calling itself).

Funnily, if I move the button code from _draw to _click, it works as expected, however, I need the GUI to redraw itself, so updating on click is impractical.

1. Is there a way, using _draw() to prevent this?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a way, using _draw() to prevent this?

No, and you shouldn’t be using the `draw` signal for this either. It has an entirely different purpose, and will be called each time a widgets redraws itself. That’s also the reason why your button is going into an infinite recursion: you changed its label so it figures it needs to be redrawn; that redraw leads to your callback being called, which again changes the label, etc etc

> 2. Is there a better way to do this?

Yes, and you mention it yourself already: make sure you do the logic of changing the widgets in the appropriate place (for example, on a click event), and let the GTK widgets take care of redrawing themselves.

Unless you’re doing something very exotic (like not running an event loop, which you automatically get with GtkApplication), this will all work fine.